# cassandra: save data in second same table or field filter

Tags: cassandra, filtering

I have table documents with columns:

```
user_id uuid,
folder_id uuid,
id uuid,
name varchar,
data blob,

and
primary key ((user_id), folder_id, id)
```

Some documents could be processed in a long time. I need to store not processed data.

I have two approaches:

1)
Add boolean column 'processed', and will filter the documents in DAO.

2)
Create second table with same structure and save data in it.

Which way is better?
Thanks.

UPDATED:

I use cql.

my queries:

```
select * from documents;
select * from documents where user_id = ...;
select * from documents where user_id = ... and folder_id = ...;
select * from documents where user_id = ... and folder_id = ... and id = ...;
```

Comment: what is your access pattern, what are some of the queries you have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no major difference.
If you use one table with boolean variable your key will change to

```
primary key ((is_processed, user_id), folder_id, id)
```

This has the overhead of one variable for each row.

So I would use two tables.